# Set Action Listener on ImageView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-imageview

Hey guys i am have a listview and it has an imageview inside of every row. what i want is when i tap/touch/click i want the checkbox to clicked like the gmail app.

my code so far is:

```
public void registerCallClickBack() {
        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View viewClicked,
                    int position, long id) {
                TextView tv1 =(TextView)viewClicked.findViewById(R.id.stock_name);
                TextView tv2 =(TextView)viewClicked.findViewById(R.id.stock_price);
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, StockItem.class);
                intent.putExtra("name", tv1.getText().toString());
                intent.putExtra("price",tv2.getText().toString());
                intent.putExtra("stockInfo", stocksList.get(position));
                startActivity(intent);



                ImageView imageCheck = (ImageView)viewClicked.findViewById(R.id.imagestartinglist);
                imageCheck.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        chk = (CheckBox)viewClicked.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxMainList);
                        if (!chk.isShown()){
                                chk.setVisibility(CheckBox.VISIBLE);
                                if(!chk.isChecked()){
                                    chk.setChecked(true);
                                }
                        }
                    }
                }); 

            }
        });
    }
```

i dont know what i am missing. and when i click on the image it checks the one i select and some others. how can i fix it??maybe with ontouch listener??
any help will be much appreciated and accepted!!!thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Which adapter are you using to set data, BaseAdapter ?

Comment: you are facing listView recycling problem. study it first